# How do I count zeroes in a range of cells only on working days in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of cells and I need to count which ones are equal to zero. However, I only want to count those where columns are equal to working days.

[image: data]

I tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(N8:AR8,"=0",N7:AR7,"=NETWORKDAYS(A7,A20,Parameters!F23:F41")
```

Answer (score 1):

Complex formulas don't work as conditions in COUNTIFS() or other conditionals. A condition has to resolve to `True` or `False`, and `"=NETWORKDAYS(A7,A20,Parameters!F23:F41"` doesn't do so.

You could add a helper row, say Row 3 in your example, to indicate the day of the week for each date. (The range addresses here are based on your image, which doesn't agree with your posted formula.)

```
E3: =Weekday(E4)
```

Copy that to `F3:AF3`.

Then your statement can exclude weekend days:

```
=COUNTIFS(E5:AF15, "=0", $E$3:$AF$3, "> 1", $E$3:$AF$3, "<7")
```

Note that this does not exlude holidays. That becomes more complicated because they are dependent on how holidays are defined for your organization or country.

[image: Screen shot]